# Borders on tables created with jspdf-Autotable are

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am creating a PDF file with a table with lines drawn only in rows.

I cannot use "grid" style, so I use `CellDef.styles` to define border styling.

However, when I enlarge or shrink my pdf on Acrobat reader, borders are not uneven.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPC9B.png)

I open it in Chrome reader and it worked the same.

Here is my code(*with only one column).

```js
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import autoTable, { RowInput } from 'jspdf-autotable';

const doc = new jsPDF({unit: "pt"});

const data = [
  [{styles: {fillColor: [105 ,105 ,105], textColor: [255 ,255 ,255],lineWidth: {bottom: 0.5, top:0,left:0,right:0} }, content: "Data 1"}],
  [{styles: {fillColor: [105 ,105 ,105], textColor: [255 ,255 ,255],lineWidth: {bottom: 0.5, top:0,left:0,right:0} }, content: "Data 1"}],
  [{styles: {fillColor: [105 ,105 ,105], textColor: [255 ,255 ,255],lineWidth: {bottom: 0.5, top:0,left:0,right:0} }, content: "Data 1"}],
  [{styles: {fillColor: [105 ,105 ,105], textColor: [255 ,255 ,255],lineWidth: {bottom: 0, top:0,left:0,right:0} }, content: "Data 1"}],
] as RowInput[]

autoTable(doc, {
  startY: 10,
  head: [['Column 1']],
  body: data,
  styles: { fontSize: 8 },
  theme: 'plain',
});

doc.save('table.pdf');
```

Libraries and environments

```
macOS 13.4.1
node v18.13.0
jspdf" 2.5.1
jspdf-autotable 3.5.29
```

- Setting `top: 0.5`

  - This works and can be a workaround, but borders are broader than I expected.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I set unit "pt" at line 3. Do you mean it does not work?